# Kentico not sending admin user password reset

Tags: email, smtp, kentico

Within the Kentico admin, when I go to a User and click the Generate New Password button, the email always fails with error message:

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not >authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication required

I have two (2) Kentico sites, running Kentico 11. Both sites have identical SMTP settings, using the same mail server, same email, same authentication, etc. On one server, the generate password emails works. I repeat, **it works**. On the other I get the error.

Test emails that I send from both sites' admin work fine. Have tried sending from the Email queue AND the System applications in the admin. Both areas on both sites work just fine, so my SMTP settings are correct.

I have tried adding to following to the appSettings:

```
<add key="CMSLogEmails" value="true"/>
<add key="CMSDebugEmails" value="true"/>
```

But nothing helpful shows up in the Event log. Even without those, nothing shows up in Event log.

Comment: Can you provide more information on your SMTP provider?  Does your SMTP provider require a whitelist of IP addresses to access the SMTP provider?   Do you have a from email address set up in the Settings for sending password resets?

Comment: Our SMTP provider is a Mdaemon client running on a AWS Windows Server instance. I have checking the whitelist and both IPs of the Kentico sites are allowed through. I checked the from email for password recovery and it was "admin@kentico.local". Once I changed it to a valid email, it worked. Thank you Brenden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to set your emails addresses in the Settings app for sending password resets.  Some SMTP providers require you to have a valid "from" email address.